# comparing a user given input to a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, user-interface, if-statement

parts of my code. it was supposed to count 2 if all of your answers were correct. 
i am just a begginer at this. the error is that when i open my browser and click the "check?" nothing happens.

```
<head>  
<script language="javascript">
function checker()
{
 var myscore = 0;

 if(parseInt(document.quiz.num1.value) == 6)
 { myscore = (myscore + 1);}
 else
 { myscore;}
 if(document.quiz.num2.value == type of "dry" )
 { myscore = (myscore + 1);}
 else
 { myscore;}

 document.myform.thescore.value = myscore;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="quiz">
How many feet are ther in 1 Fathom? <input type="text" id="num1">
<br>
What type of stones can never be found in the ocean? <input type="text" id="num2">
<br>

My Score: <input type="text" id="thescore"><br>
<input type="button" value="Check?" onClick="checker()">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: i think that you dont have to declare the 'num2' variable in your function. it is not needed. plus in your form, you need to call the function 'chechker' sommewhere.

Comment: i have deleted it...  still, my code has an error.

Comment: why dont you poost your full code? and also the error?

Comment: <input type="button" value="Check?" onClick="checker()"> i already had it to

Comment: make the type to 'submit'... and inside your checker... add a print statement at the very beginning and then run... it will tell you if your function is being called or not.

Comment: i have uploaded my whole code as you said.

Comment: i tried it... i think my only problem is this.. if(document.quiz.num2.value == type of "dry" ).. @aradhna

Comment: well that is part of the problem... but after that also your script is not running..... why dont you try to use getElementById() function?

Comment: i don't know how to use it..

Comment: i copied your code and executed it.... your script is not being called... you have to check that.

Comment: @aradhana what could be the problem?

Comment: i found the problem... it was on .. onClick="checker()" .. i edited it to onclick="checker()" ... i just need the right logic for f(document.quiz.num2.value == type of "dry" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your answer:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script lang="Java-Script">
            var msg;
            var sc;
            function validateTest()
            {
                sc=0;
                msg=document.frm.num1.value;
                if(msg==6)
                    sc=sc+1;
                msg=document.frm.num2.value;
                if(msg=='dry')
                    sc=sc+1;

                document.frm.thescore.value=sc;
                return;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="frm">
            How many feet are there in 1 Fathom? <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
            What type of stones can never be found in the ocean? <input type="text" name="num2"><br>

            My Score: <input type="text" name="thescore"><br>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validateTest()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

i have already tested this, it will work.

Comment: is it the check icon that turns green?

Comment: will the code still work if my answer is more than one word? for example.. 'help me' or 'power booster track' .?

Comment: if you have only ONE string as your answer, then all you need to do is change the value in your checker function. if your answer can be TWO OR MORE strings, then you can use an OR to check or you can also use a regular expression.